# Why is the param name different betwee these two routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two routes that I want to point to the same controller action.

```
get '/events/:url_token' , to: 'events#show'

get '/tv/events/:url_token', to: 'events#show'
```

and in my EventsContoller for the show action I set the event with

```
@event = Event.find_by(url_token: params['id'])
```

This works fine when I navigate to /events/asdf, because the params look like

> {"id"=>"asdf"}

but when I navigate to /tv/events/asdf I'm getting

> {"url_token"=>"hbbnHw"}

I don't understand why the param name is different with these two routings or how I should fix.

EDIT: I've also got this in my routes related to events:

```
resources :events do
  member do
    post :addeventgroup
    patch :updateeventtype
    patch :updateeventgroup
    patch :start_event
  end
```

Comment: could you show more code ? like your full `routes.rb` and how you navigate to the url ? did you use `link_to` `button_to` manual `href` or typing manually

Comment: You have probably another route defined in your `routes.rb` that handles the `events` routes already. Perhaps a `resources :events`? Please show your `routes.rb`.

Comment: @spickermann Yes, I added an edit for what I have in routes related to events...

Comment: @buncis I am accessing the url manually. I added more from my routes.rb

Comment: Why do you want to have two routes pointing at the same URL? Why don't you use the same URL? What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`resources :events` adds multiple routes to your application – one of them is similar to the following pattern:

```
get '/events/:id', to: 'events#show'
```

When you do not want that route and instead want to use one you defined with

```
get '/events/:url_token' , to: 'events#show'
```

then you can disable the route generated by `resources :events` like this:

```
resources(:events, except: :show) do
  member do
    # ...
  end  
end
```

I suggest reading the [Rails Guides about Routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Alternatively you can just remove this `get '/events/:url_token', to: 'events#show'` definition and rename the parameter in the other like this:

```
get '/tv/events/:id', to: 'events#show'
```